# validation :group of radio button

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm try to validate form contain diffrent group for radio buttons but the problem is that it's only one that work from all of them ..I tried to follow the same pattren [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212849/radio-button-validation-through-javascript) but it still not working
 ,,**I don't know what is go wrong**

```
function validateRadio(radios) {
  for (i = 0; i < radios.length; ++i) {
    if (radios[i].checked) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function validate() {
  /* validate Radio button */

  if (validateRadio(document.forms["Registration"]["gender"])) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('select one value !');
    return false;
  }

  if (validateRadio(document.forms["Registration"]["maritalstatus"])) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('select one value!');
    return false;
  }

  if (validateRadio(document.forms["Registration"]["monthincome"])) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('select one value !');
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Is this one still open or did you manage to solve your issue by now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the result of the validation in a variable and return it at the end. return exits the function and in your case never gets past the first check. Also think about replacing the `alert()` with something else, they are not really best practice anymore.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Here is an example

```
function validate(){
    let tValidation = true;

    if(!validateRadio(document.forms["Registration"]["gender"])){
        alert('select a gender!');
        tValidation = false;
    };

    if(!validateRadio(document.forms["Registration"]["maritalstatus"])){
        alert('select a martialstatus!');
        tValidation = false;
    };

    if(!validateRadio(document.forms["Registration"]["monthincome"])){
        alert('select a monthly income!');
        tValidation = false;
    };

    return tValidation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (validateRadio(document.forms["Registration"]["gender"]))` is returning `true` or `false` which is exiting the function before it gets to check the rest.

Simply check all 3 at the same time.

```
function validate() {
    if (validateRadio(document.forms["Registration"]["gender"])
        && validateRadio(document.forms["Registration"]["maritalstatus"])
        && validateRadio(document.forms["Registration"]["monthincome"])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('select one value !');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<form name="Registration">
  <p>
  <input name="gender" type="radio" value="M" /> Male
  <input name="gender" type="radio" value="F" /> Female  
  </p>
  <p>
  <input name="maritalstatus" type="radio" value="M" /> Married
  <input name="maritalstatus" type="radio" value="S" /> Single 
  </p>
  <p>
  <input name="monthincome" type="radio" value="Y" /> Yes
  <input name="monthincome" type="radio" value="N" /> No 
  </p>
</form>
<button onClick="validate()">Validate</button>


<script>
  function validateRadio(radios) {
    for (i = 0; i < radios.length; ++i) {
      if (radios[i].checked) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  function validate() {
    var frm = document.forms["Registration"];
    /* validate Radio button */

    if (!validateRadio(frm.gender)) {
      alert('select one value for gender !');
      return false;
    }

    if (!validateRadio(frm.maritalstatus)) {
      alert('select one value for maritalstatus!');
      return false;
    }

    if (!validateRadio(frm.monthincome)) {
      alert('select one value for monthincome !');
      return false;
    }

    alert('All good');
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: No comment, no explanation?